# Sharing report parameters between cubes and views/tables

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Is it possible to share parameters between a DataSet based on Cubes, and a DataSet based on views/tables?

As my report currently is, I am filtering the DataSet based on cubes by setting the filter to be a parameter in the query designer. This produces the desired effect of cascading etc that one wants from a report based on cubes, and generates new parameters.

I have another DataSet that needs to be filtered using the same parameters, but based on views. I tried to use the following in the WHERE clause:

```
AND <FieldIdentifier> IN @<ParameterName>
```

This seems to filter the entire data set out. Has anyone had any problems with this before?

Any answers are really appreciated. If you need any more information, I will definitely provide it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this will work due to the syntax differences between MDX and SQL the clause that you need in the parameters are different.

To solve this in the past I have use a report function function to make the conversion from the Rs parameter for the SQL and generate the correct MDX slicers. but this will require a bit of custom code and a good understanding of MDX.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Jason! I don't know that it is correct but I will have to assume it is so and mark your answer with an up-vote.